# Why is my field not nullable when no value is NULL?

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, null

I am quite new to arcpy.
My script seemed to work just fine but I get an error, "the field is not nullable". I guess the problem is with the last block of code but I don't understand why nor how to get around.

Some of the original columns ['T2TC1', 'T2TC2', 'T2TC3','T2TC4','T2TC5'] are equal to 0. No value in my "TOT_Count" column is equal to 0, so I am not dividing by 0.

TOT_Count is the sum of ['T2TC1', 'T2TC2', 'T2TC3','T2TC4','T2TC5']. This seems to be creating the problem but I don't know why. If I replace the values of this column by a random number the problem disapears.

```
import arcpy
table = "C:\Users\Me\Documents\datas\Count\FinalT4.shp"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#input fields with counts#
fields = ['T2TC1', 'T2TC2', 'T2TC3','T2TC4','T2TC5'] # etc.
newFields = []

#create a new f field corresponding to each field#
for field in fields:
    field_name ="F_" + field
    arcpy.AddField_management (table, field_name, "FLOAT")
    newFields.append(field_name)

#for each new field created, calculate the old field divided by the sum#
for newField in newFields:
    for field in fields :
        expr =  '(!{}! / !TOT_Count!)'.format(field)
        arcpy.CalculateField_management (table, newField, expr, 'PYTHON')
```

Comment: For each new field you are calculating "old field / sum of all old fields" for each old field. This cant be what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look at your nested for loops. Every 'newField' is going to end up with the exact same number which is 'T2TC5' / TOT_Count.

I'm not sure if this is what is causing your issue as I don't use ArcPy a lot and the 'zone' you mention in the error statement seems a bit odd. But try using this code.

```
itCount = 0
while (itCount < len(fields):
     expr = '(!{}! / !TOT_Count!)'.format(fields[itCount])
     arcpy.CalculateField_management (table, newFields[itCount], expr, 'PYTHON')
     itCount+=1
```

---

Where you have AddField_management(table,field_name,"FLOAT") change it to AddField_management(table,field_name,"FLOAT",field_is_nullab‌​le=True) and see where the null values are being added. Then you can provide more detail on where the error is occuring

Comment: I was confused, I mean the field is not nullable.
I tried your code. It doesn't solve the issue. 
Apparently it has something to do with my TOT_Count column (which is the sum of the 5 columns ['T2TC1', 'T2TC2', 'T2TC3','T2TC4','T2TC5']). I changed the value of TOT_Count to 100 and then the script runs.

Comment: Where you have AddField_management(table,field_name,"FLOAT") change it to  AddField_management(table,field_name,"FLOAT",field_is_nullable=True) and see where the null values are being added

Comment: @Freighty Please [edit] your answer to add more detail rather than in comments.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why your code does not work but anyway, you can try this:

I think you should use the [da.UpdateCursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) instead of the Field Calculator:

> UpdateCursor establishes read-write access to records returned from a
>   feature class or table.

Using cursor will give you much more flexibility. Replace your code after adding the fields with:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(table,newFields+fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        oldsum=sum(row[4:])
        row[0]=row[5]/oldsum
        row[1]=row[6]/oldsum
        row[2]=row[7]/oldsum
        row[3]=row[8]/oldsum
        row[4]=row[9]/oldsum
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```